# PPTP VPN connection failed after 1-2 min (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, networking, vmware, vpn, pptp

My pptp vpn connection always failed after 1-2mins
I'm try solving it by http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2222063
and also check the "Use point-to-point encryption" box.
but its still failed

How can I solve this problem?

is it happen because of client and server are in the same subnet?
server 192.168.149.131 and client 192.168.149.130
both are on VMWare and using 2 network adapter for each machines
(1 NAT and 1 Host-Only)

Comment: In many cases it happens because of unreliable internet connection! Sometimes because of ipconflicts. Investigate syslog for more correct information